# Which airlines did use a HUD for their A380?

Tags: airbus-a380, hud

Which airlines did (or still do) use a HUD for their A380 ?

Answer (score 5):

According to this [SNPL bulletin from 2015](https://snpl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Spe%CC%81cial-Cometec-N%C2%B012.pdf) (French airline pilots union):

- Asiana and Korean A380 have a single HUD,
- Air France and Qatar A380 have a dual HUD.

In addition Qatar wanted all their planes to be equipped with HUD in the mid-term.

Planes still flying:

- Asiana: 5 flying and 1 parked
- Korean: 5 flying and 5 parked
- Air France: None since 2020 (had 10 aircraft)
- Quatar: 8 flying and 2 parked

(according to [Planespotters.net](https://www.planespotters.net).)

Interestingly, [China airports authority](https://www.thalesgroup.com/en/worldwide/aerospace/news/head-displays-rapidly-expanding-market) requires domestic airlines to have a quota of HUD-equipped aircraft (now 50%, 100% in 2025) in order to speed up airport operations, specially in low visibility. The HUD will need to integrate the image from an infrared camera fixed on the nose.

Comment: I wonder how the China requirement would have affected the A380. HUD allows aircraft without autoland to land in CAT IIIa conditions, but that would be a moot point for A380 which already has autoland. Maybe in China they have different RVR minimums for HUD? Or maybe the Thales article didn't apply to the A380.

Comment: My guess is the IR sensor mostly help detect heat from the approach and centerline lights in fog. It can help the pilot to decide to abort a landing, e.g. if the projected touchdown point is not safe. (It could affect China if one of its airline buys a A380 from a foreign company.)

Comment: I'm just wondering if regulations in China have different minimums or RVR requirements for fail operational autoland with HUD vs fail operational autoland without HUD. Could be, but if not then it doesn't seem like it would affect the number of A380 landings. Of course that doesn't stop them from making it a requirement for all planes. Makes things safer anyway.